# javascript arrays difference

Tags: javascript, arrays

am confused what this code deos so can anyone explian it to me the reason behind it.

```
function diff(arr1, arr2) {
 var newArr = [];
 var h1 = Object.create(null);
 arr1.forEach(function(e) {
   h1[e] = e;
 });

 var h2 = Object.create(null);
 arr2.forEach(function(e) {
   h2[e] = e;
 });

 Object.keys(h1).forEach(function(e) {
   if (!(e in h2)) newArr.push(h1[e]);
 });
 Object.keys(h2).forEach(function(e) {
   if (!(e in h1)) newArr.push(h2[e]);
 });

 return newArr;
}
```

i found it when i was searching how to get the difference between javascript arrays

breif explanation will be help full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing 2 Arrays and finding all the differences is slow. The reason is because the lookup time is not fast.

Say you have the following:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4];
var arr2 = [5,6,7,8];
```

What you want is to find every value in arr1 that isn't in arr2, AND every value in arr2 that isn't in arr1. To do this, you loop over arr1 and ask "is this value in arr2?" But each time you ask that, you have to also loop over arr2. Then, you have to repeat this again with arr2, looking up each value in arr1.

This Javascript method speeds things up. In Javascript, Objects are created as a set of unique keys and their corresponding values. For instance:

```
var obj1 = {a: "string a", 6: "number 6"};
```

Now, I can say `obj1['a']` and it will return "string a". Not only can the keys and values be any time (number, string, Object), but the lookup is instantaneous. We no longer have to look at every key in obj1, so if we can take advantage of this, our logic would be much faster.

The first thing this Javascript method does is convert both Arrays into Objects. It uses the Array values as both the Object key and value, and we end up with h1 and h2.

Then, it does the logic I mentioned above. It looks at every key in h1 (this optimization eliminated duplicate Array values, because the Object key must be unique), and if that key is not in h2, it adds the value to newArr. Then this repeats for all keys in h2.

Basically, it optimizes our search by reorganizing our slow Array values into fast key-value Objects, then does the necessary comparisons.

Comment: thank you so much @Nate i now understand and i can use it in another places